# Cross-compile Node.js contextify for ARM

Tags: linux, node.js, arm, jsdom, contextify

I'm trying to cross-compile the *node.js* module **contextify** (as part of **jsdom**) for ARM platform on my 64bit Fedora installation. However, I seem unable to build for any other platform than the one I'm running on. I've tried different ways such as running `node-gyp --arch=arm configure rebuild`, or also `node-gyp configure --without-snapshot --dest-cpu=arm --dest-os=linux --with-arm-float-abi=softfp rebuild` (a command I've found online somewhere when looking for this problem).

The build runs successful without giving warnings or errors. However, it seems the target architecture just doesn't matter. I always end up with the a binary for my own 64bit system, not for ARM anything else I've tried. Using `ia32` didn't change anything either - it looks like the provided parameters just have no effect. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's a complete console output:

```
bash-4.2# node-gyp clean configure --arch=arm rebuild
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@1.0.2
gyp info using node@0.10.29 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/src/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/.node-gyp/0.10.29/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/.node-gyp/0.10.29',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/src/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/src/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/.node-gyp/0.10.29/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/.node-gyp/0.10.29',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/src/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory `/src/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build'
make: Warning: File `contextify.target.mk' has modification time 0.044 s in the future
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/contextify/src/contextify.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/contextify.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/contextify.node: Finished
  COPY Release/contextify.node
make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
make: Leaving directory `/src/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/build'
gyp info ok
```

Comment: Do you have the appropriate `CC`, `CXX`, etc. environment variables set up for the cross compiler?

Comment: OMG. I really, really feel stupid now. `CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.7 CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.7 node-gyp clean configure --arch=arm rebuild` does the trick... Thanks, mscdex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you have the appropriate CC, CXX, etc. environment variables set up for the cross compiler before invoking `node-gyp` so that it knows which compiler to use.