# Cross-compile node module with native bindings with node-gyp

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cross-compiling, node-gyp, aws-lambda

I'm using AWS Lambda, which involves creating an archive of my node.js script, including the `node_modules` folder and uploading that to their infrastructure to run.

This works fine, except when it comes to node modules with native bindings (using node-gyp). Because the binding was complied and project archived on my local computer (OS X), it is not compatible with AWS's (Amazon Linux) servers.

How can I cross-compile/install a node module (specifically, [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)) so when I upload it to another server arch it runs?

Comment: Have you tried utilizing node-pre-gyp? node-sqlit3 already uses it, so you're ahead of the game there. IIRC, it should offload the build to Amazon S3, so you can compile against Amazon Linux (AWS Lambda's OS).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that node-sqlite3 uses node-pre-gyp, but I didn't really understand what that means for me or how to use it to achieve what I want.

Comment: I know it involves additionnal cost, but i d suggest to package ad build onto another s3 box. Then transfer it to your production environment. Note that if you d do npm i from your linux environment, everything would work fine out of the box if you have the required build tools.

Comment: Does this help any? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797424/cross-compile-node-js-contextify-for-arm It basically says you need to have the right environment variables for it to know which compiler to use.

Comment: Yeah that's a start, but I have no idea what compilers I need or what to set the env vars to. I've tried looking up and finding what I need, but found it overly difficult to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While not really a solution to your problem, a very easy workaround could be to simply compile the native addons on a Linux machine.

For your particular situation, I would use [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com). Vagrant can create virtual machines and configure them within seconds.

1. Find an OS image that resembles Amazon's Linux distro (Fedora, CentOS, others that use `yum` as package manager - see [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager#Front_ends))
2. Use a simple configuration script that, when run by Vagrant on machine startup, will run `npm install` (optionally it might also remove the *node_modules* folder before to ensure a clean installation)
3. For extra comfort, the script can also create the zip file for deployment
4. Once the installation finishes, the script will shutdown the VM to avoid unnecessary consumption of system resources
5. Deploy!

It might require some tuning if the linked libraries are not at the same place on the target machine but generally this seems to me like the best and quickest solution.

Comment: While it might not be a solution to my *question*, it does solve my problem. Thanks - I'll look into this

Comment: I'd love to see a "real" solution to this; I'd like to install node-sqlite on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @RichardTurner There should be no issue with that - just `npm install` it on the target machine.

Comment: @rossman Yep, you're right, I just needed to add some swap to overcome a shortage of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

While installing the app using Vagrant might be sufficient in some cases, I have found it necessary to build the app on Linux which is **as close to Lambda's Amazon Linux AMI as possible**.

You can read the original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34019739/303184

Steps to make it work:

1. Spawn new EC2 instance. Make sure it is based on *exactly the same* image as your AWS Lambda runtime. You can review Lambda env details here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html. In our case, it was Amazon Linux AMI called **amzn-ami-hvm-2015.03.0.x86_64-gp2**.
2. Install `nvm` and use it to install the same version of Node.js as on the AWS Lambda. At the time of writing this, it was **v0.10.36**. You can refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html again to find out.
3. You will probably need to install git & g++ compiler on the EC2. You can do this running

   ```
   sudo yum install git gcc-c++
   ```
4. Finally, clone your app to your new EC2 and install your app's dependecies:

   ```
   nvm use 0.10.36
   npm install --production
   ```
5. You can then easily download the node_modules using `scp` or such.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10399857)

Comment: @Eloims I have attached the full solution as requested.

Answer (score 1):

Same lines as Robert's answer, when I had to work on my MAC in a different OS I use vm ware like Oracle's free virtualizer [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to get a linux on my mac, no cost to me. Or sign up for a new AWS account, you get a micro for a year free. Use that to get your linux box, do whatever you need there.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has a page describing how to deal with native NPM modules: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/